# Updating client view from server without client call (C# MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Client 1:  Is a simple view with a message obtained from database,  "My message"

Client 2: other view of same server, this client update the message from database "My NEW message"

When client 2 update the message, i want that Client 1 navigator was updated and show "My NEW message".  Is it possible?

A way to do that could be exec a automatic ajax call every X seconds... but i prefer that server send a message to the other client updating his view.

I have no clue if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out Microsft's SignalR technology, it provides the functionality you are looking for, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET SignalR](http://asp.net/sirnalr) is what you need.

Please read more here:

- [SignalR official site](http://asp.net/sirnalr)
- [SignalR.net](http://signalr.net)